# Is this a concrete parameterized type?

Tags: java

If I understand correctly, the following is a Generic Type:

```
class Example<T> {}
```

And the following is a Concrete Parameterized Type:

```
Example<String>
```

And the following is *not* a Concrete Parameterized Type:

```
Example<? extends Number>
```

Given the following, can somebody explain to me whether Example is a Concrete Parameterized Type?

```
Example< OtherExample<? extends Number> >
```

If it is not Concrete, is it true to say that if a type argument itself is a Wildcard, or any *nested* type argument is a Wildcard, that the outermost type is therefore not Concrete?

**Update**

I realize now that the term Concrete Parameterized Type may not be official Java terminology.

I picked it up from the following source: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic2

**Conclusion**

I have been persuaded that:

```
Example< OtherExample<? extends Number> >
```

Is a Concrete Parameterized Type (so far as the terminology of the GenericsFAQ intended) because it contains no wildcard ("?") directly, and can be used with the "new" keyword.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Elsewhere in here FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ301) Angelika says this:

> A wildcard parameterized type is not a concrete type that could appear in a  new expression.

But to expand on this, I'd say that there are a few different kinds of types that can be provided as a type argument.

Given the example class:

```
class Example<T> {
    T value;
}
```

#### Raw type (no type argument):

```
new Example();
```

A raw type is sort of like "erasure of" the type. Since `T` has no bound, a raw `Example<T>` behaves a lot like an `Example<Object>`. The difference being that the raw type causes the generic type system to be largely ignored. In practice, don't use it. It is for backwards compatibility.

#### Generic type argument (type comes from somewhere else):

```
class HasExample<T> {
    Example<T> myExample = new Example<T>();

    HasExample(T value) {
        myExample.value = value;
    }
}
```

The type of `Example` then receives whatever type is supplied to `HasExample`.

#### 'Concrete' type argument:

```
new Example<String>();
```

This means the type of example is actually known.

Along with raw types and generic, those are the three ways a generic class can be instantiated.

#### Wildcard type argument (unknown):

```
static void handle(Example<?> example) {
    System.out.println(example.value);
}
```

The wildcard denotes that `Example` once *had* a concrete type but we are not sure what it was. Since we don't know what it was, the wildcard disallows usage of the parameterized members in certain ways. In the above method we can still print it (invoking `toString` indirectly) because we can be sure it's an `Object`.

About whether the complex declaration should be considered concrete, it's both yes and no, but I'd say mostly yes. Suppose we have the following additional class:

```
class Holder<T> {
    T held;
}
```

It's possible then to do the following:

```
Holder<Example<? extends Number>> holder =
    new Holder<Example<? extends Number>>();
```

The type argument to `holder` is a concrete type: `Example`, in the sense that:

- It's not a type variable or wildcard *itself*, despite containing a wildcard.
- We can instantiate a new instance of the `Holder` with this type.

It's probably useful to think about the types of `Holder` and `Example` separately, because their respective type arguments have different effects on what we can do with the `Holder` instance.

We can do these sorts of actions:

```
Example<Integer> example = new Example<Integer>();
example.value = Integer.valueOf(0);
// set holder.held
holder.held = example;
// get holder.held, but we lose some type information
Example<? extends Number> example = holder.held;
// access and use a member of the Example
Number number = example.value;
System.out.println(number.intValue());
```

However, we can't do this:

```
// set parameterized member of the Example
holder.held.value = Integer.valueOf(1);
```

That's an effect of the wildcard, and it's why we could say that the declared type of `holder` is "not fully concrete". However, note that this is an effect on the nested object. The wildcard doesn't directly restrict the way we're able to use the `Holder` instance. It only restricts the way we're able to use the member of the `Example` instance.

For these reasons, I'd say that it's reasonable to think of types like `A<B<? extends C>>` (with nested wildcards) as concrete, but with a few caveats.

Comment: Mentioning the difference between "unknown" and "delegated" was very helpful - because a delegated type can be used with the new keyword (other answers/comments seemed to imply otherwise but I think you are correct).

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the case of the delegation, the type is "unknown" when you make a new instance in the source file but we assume that the type will actually be filled in with something concrete. The wildcard means that there *was* a type originally. So we can't do a `new Example<?>` but we can do a `new Holder<Example<?>>` because the Holder must get the Example from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand concrete is for class not being abstract.
'Parametrized' or ***Generic*** (my preferred way of calling it) is as you've correctly guessed Example and unbounded wildcard `?` has to do with it being concrete as Example is the same as Example.

That said, you can call `abstract class Example<T>` a not concrete generic type, but I've never saw anyone calling it such.

So taking into consideration the terminology from the source you've mentioned they claim concrete to mean the lack of wildcard (unbounded, `?`, is the only they mention - so not sure if bounded types are also 'not' concrete). I can only recommend you another source on information on the issue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: I read about Java generics on this page http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic2 and picked up the terminology from there.

Comment: The Java documentation says "An invocation of a generic type is generally known as a parameterized type." so I do not think it is helpful to use the term 'Generic' and 'Parameterized' interchangably. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: So taking into consideration the terminology from the source you've mentioned they claim concrete to mean the lack of wildcard (unbounded, `?`, is the only they mention - so not sure if bounded type are also 'not' concrete). I can only recommend you another source on information on the issue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: FantasticJamieBurns, I never call them parametrised types - that's why I put that in quotes, if that was your question. As for me, generics are not even close to parametrised types as there's type erasure on the JVM at runtime.

Comment: Angelika is JavaChampion and a JCP member, so dont mess with she :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a difference with

```
class MyClass<T>{}
```

where you don't know what is the parameter of T and :

```
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass<String>
```

where you know now what is the type of MyOtherClass which **is** a MyClass.

There are funny stuff with wildcards

```
class MyClass<? extends Number>{}
class MyOtherClass extends MyClass<Integer>
```

but the idea is the same;

However

```
  MyUnfinishedClass<T> extends MyClass<T>
```

would not be concrete because `T` is not known yet.

Your [source](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic2) - which is known as one of the best page on generics - says about the same. MyClass is not a concrete parameterized class, and MyOtherCLass is a concrete Parameterized class.
The JVM will create a new class for each different Parameterized class wich will cause the distinction between     `class MyIntegerClass extends MyClass<Integer>` and     `class MyDoubleClass extends MyClass<Double>` and even `class MyNumberClass extends MyClass<Number>`.

This is known as contravariance which might be your next question.

Comment: I read about Java generics on this page http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Topic2 and picked up the terminology from there.

Comment: @NicolasZozol `MyIntegerClass2 extends MyClass<Integer>` is also a different class... but at the end of the day, `MyInteger.class.getSuperclass().equals(MyDoubleClass.class.getSuperClass())`

Answer (score 0):

<del>The only difference is `?`. Type without `?` are **concrete parameterized type**.</del>

The only difference are wildcards (bounded like `T` and unbounded like `?`). Type without wildcards are **concrete parameterized type**.

Comment: Not entirely... only wildcards used in the immediate class make it non-concrete.  If a class' immediate type parameters are wildcard generics, that class is still concrete.

Comment: No, for exemple, MyOtherClass<T> extends MyClass<T> is not concrete. The type is not known yet, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

`Example< OtherExample<? extends Number> >` is concrete: that is to say, you can instantiate an instance of this class.  Just like you can instantiate `ArrayList<Collection<?>>`.

Comment: Re-reading the following from the source "[A] concrete parameterized type [is] ... An instantiation of a generic type where all type arguments are concrete types rather than wildcards" I am struggling to understand how Example in this case can be concrete when OtherExample is not (by the same definition). If we agree that OtherExample is not concrete, how can it then satisfy the requirement that Example have all concrete type arguments in order for itself to become concrete? (my head is spinning!)

Comment: It should more accurately say "An instantiation of a generic type where all immediate type arguments are neither wildcards or generic types".  For `Map<K, V>`, this means both `K` and `V` must not be `?`, `? extends Whatever`, or `? super Whatever`.  `HashMap<String, Collection<?>>` satisfies this, and can be instantiated (and even populated).